# Getting a Python Class to display user inputted variables

Tags: python

I am trying to follow a Python tutorial to get a user to input variables and then my class will output it depending on what they inputted. the tutorial hard codes the values and i can get that to work but i am trying to go to the next step and get them to input values and use them. so far all the code does is let them enter values put does not post them to the output. below is both sets of code

here is the code from the tutorial i am using: (can be found here:`http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_classes_objects.htm`)

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class Employee:
   'Common base class for all employees'
   empCount = 0

   def __init__(self, name, salary):
      self.name = name
      self.salary = salary
      Employee.empCount += 1

   def displayCount(self):
     print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount

   def displayEmployee(self):
      print "Name : ", self.name,  ", Salary: ", self.salary

"This would create first object of Employee class"
emp1 = Employee("Zara", 2000)
"This would create second object of Employee class"
emp2 = Employee("Manni", 5000)
emp1.displayEmployee()
emp2.displayEmployee()
print "Total Employee %d" % Employee.empCount
```

here is my code

```
class People:

    personName = input('Enter your name: ')
    personAge = input('Enter your age: ')

    def __init__(self, personName, personAge):
        self.personName = personName
        self.personAge = personAge

    def displayPerson(self):
        print "Name : ", self.personName,  ", Age: ", self.personAge

person1 = People(personName, personAge)
person1.displayPerson()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the input code out of the class statement,like this.

```
class People:

def __init__(self, personName, personAge):
    self.personName = personName
    self.personAge = personAge

def displayPerson(self):
    print "Name : ", self.personName,  ", Age: ", self.personAge

personName = input('Enter your name: ')
personAge = input('Enter your age: ')
person1 = People(personName, personAge)
person1.displayPerson()
```

Answer (score 0):

You're doing this at the wrong place. You need to do this outside the class, at the point where you're instantiating them:

```
personName = raw_input('Enter your name: ')
personAge = raw_input('Enter your age: ')
person1 = People(personName, personAge)
person1.displayPerson()
```

Note that since this appears to be Python 2.7, you should use `raw_input` instead of `input`. Also you should inherit your class from `object`.